# Unable to find pythonXX.dll on Windows 7 environment

Tags: windows-7, windows, python

I have an application that runs off a virtual python environment, what I need to do is find the `pythonXX.dll` (xx being the version), I've done some research and found it should be in c:\windows\system however when I try to look for it, it isn't there.

```
C:\Users\z-perkins-thomas\Desktop\work_tool>where python**.***
C:\Windows\System32\pythoncom27.dll
C:\Windows\System32\pythoncomloader27.dll
C:\Python27\python.exe
C:\Python27\pythonw.exe

C:\Users\z-perkins-thomas\Desktop\work_tool>
```

As you can see it seems that I don't have the `dll` unless it's one of the ones above. I've checked in the following:

- `python27\Lib`
- `python27\DLLs`
- `%systemroot%\syswow64`
- `python27\libs`

It seems to be nowhere to be found, is there a reason I can't find this, or is it just not there?

---

Well.. I found the `dll` file here: `C:\Users\z-perkins-thomas\rest-api\Scripts\python27.dll` but that doesn't explain why I can run a python script successfully?

Comment: Have you installed Python on the computer? Python is not included with Windows and must be installed separately.

Comment: @LMiller7 Lol yes, I probably should have specified that, python is on the computer `C:\Python27\python.exe` is the executable to run python. It's on the computer and it's working I can run any python program I want successfully

Comment: @LMiller7 I found it in a random directory in the middle of nowhere?